# Alfresco Share: what shall I do to integrate electronic signatures?

Tags: alfresco

I'd like to have reliable document workflow within *Alfresco Share (Community Edition)*. What shall I do to let site users have electronic signatures when they process documents?

I googled awhile but in vain.

Comment: Alfresco already has built in workflow support, so that part is covered. In terms of electronic signatures, what kind of signature do you want and when would you want users to apply them?

Comment: `http://www.ziaconsulting.com/zsign-electronic-signature-alfresco/`
Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The [PDF Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-pdf-toolkit/) provides digital signature functionality for PDFs, which may provide some ideas on how to extend Alfresco to support a more general digital signature feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom java class to load in a document and put the digital signature there e.g.:

```
<node name="signDocument">
    <event type="node-enter">
        <action class="mypackage.SignDigitalDocument">
                <document>
                    // Document node
                </document>
                <user>
                    // User name, maybe for adding a signature label
                </user>
                <signature>
                    // Digital signature.........
                </signature>
            </action
    </event>
</node>
```

Within the custom Java class you can read the entries and do e.g. a FileInputStream and get the document. Just look at [Content Transformers](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformations) Here you should have enough info to code your own tranformer.